# External properties file in grails 3

Tags: grails

I need read configuration from a external file properties in grails 3. In grails 2.x I link the file with:

```
grails.config.locations = ["classpath:config.properties"]
```

In the config.groovy, but this file do not exists in grails 3.

Have you any idea for solve?

Comment: Is your question, what happened to Config.groovy?  It was renamed to application.groovy in Spring 3.x.

Comment: yes, but I dont know, how use external configurations files, as I do in grails 2.x.

Answer (score 7):

Because Grails 3 is built on Spring Boot, you can use the Spring Boot mechanisms for externalized properties. Namely, using the `spring.config.location` command line parameter, or the `SPRING_BOOT_LOCATION` environment variable. [Here's the Spring documentation page on it](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

The example the documentation provides for the command line parameter is this:

```
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties
```

The way I have been using it is by setting an environment variable, like this:

```
export SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION="/home/user/application-name/application.yml"
```

One of the nice features is that you can leave some properties in the properties file that is bundled in the app, but if there are some properties you do not want to include (such as passwords), those can be set specifically in the external config file.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at https://gist.github.com/reduardo7/d14ea1cd09108425e0f5ecc8d3d7fca0

### External configuration in Grails 3

Working on *Grails 3* I realized that I no longer can specify external configuration using the standard `grails.config.locations` property in `Config.groovy` file.

Reason is obvious! There is no `Config.groovy` now in *Grails 3*. Instead we now use `application.yml` to configure the properties. However, you can't specify the external configuration using this file too!

**What the hack?**

Now Grails 3 uses Spring's property source concept. To enable external config file to work we need to do something extra now.

Suppose I want to override some properties in `application.yml` file with my external configuration file.

E.g., from this:

```
  dataSource:
    username: sa
    password:
    driverClassName: "org.h2.Driver"
```

To this:

```
dataSource:
  username: root
  password: mysql
  driverClassName: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
```

First I need to place this file in application's root. E.g., I've following structure of my Grails 3 application with external configuration file `app-config.yml` in place:

```
[human@machine tmp]$ tree -L 1 myapp
myapp
├── app-config.yml // <---- external configuration file!
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
├── gradle.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── grails-app
└── src
```

Now, to enable reading this file just add following:

**To your `build.gradle` file**

```
bootRun {
  // local.config.location is just a random name. You can use yours.
  jvmArgs = ['-Dlocal.config.location=app-config.yml']
}
```

**To your `Application.groovy` file**

```
package com.mycompany

import grails.boot.GrailsApp
import grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean
import org.springframework.context.EnvironmentAware
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {
    public final static String LOCAL_CONFIG_LOCATION = "local.config.location"

    static void main(String[] args) {
        GrailsApp.run(Application, args)
    }

    @Override
    void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        String configPath = System.properties[LOCAL_CONFIG_LOCATION]

        if (!configPath) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Local configuration location variable is required: " + LOCAL_CONFIG_LOCATION)
        }

        File configFile = new File(configPath)
        if (!configFile.exists()) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Configuration file is required: " + configPath)
        }

        Resource resourceConfig = new FileSystemResource(configPath)
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean ypfb = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean()
        ypfb.setResources([resourceConfig] as Resource[])
        ypfb.afterPropertiesSet()
        Properties properties = ypfb.getObject()
        environment.propertySources.addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource(LOCAL_CONFIG_LOCATION, properties))
    }
}
```

Notice that `Application` class implements `EnvironmentAware` Interface and overrides its `setEnvironment(Environment environment):void` method.

Now this is all what you need to re-enable external config file in Grails 3 application.

Code and guidance is taken from following links with little modification:

1. http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-3-External-config-td4658823.html
2. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grails-dev-discuss/_5VtFz4SpDY

Source: https://gist.github.com/ManvendraSK/8b166b47514ca817d36e

Comment: After "grails war" that "app-config.yml" file wont be inside of the directory, and the configuration will not be loaded.

There is a workaround to that: on "src/main" directory create other dir named "resources" (src/main/resources) and put the configuration file (app-config.yml) there.

Load the file with this:

`def url = getClass().classLoader.getResource("app-config.yml")`
`def file = new File(url.toURI())`


`Resource resourceConfig = new FileSystemResource(file)`

Like that u will be able to load the external configuration file in production and development mode.

Comment: It seems this no longer works in grails 4.0.2+

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same problem to read the properties file from external location in Grails 3. I found this [plugin](https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/external-config) which helpme to read the properties from external location. It has feature to read .yml, .groovy files as well.

Follow the steps mentioned in the documentation and it will work.
The steps are like:

1. Add dependency in build.gradle:

   ```
   dependencies {compile 'org.grails.plugins:external-config:1.2.2'}
   ```
2. Add this in `application.yml` grails:

   ```
   config:
       locations:
           - file:///opt/abc/application.yml
   ```
3. Create file at external location. In my case `/opt/abc/application.yml`.
4. Build the application and run.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use

def cfg = new ConfigSlurper.parse(getClass().classLoader.getResource('path/myExternalConfigfile.groovy'))
```

Answer (score 1):

When running from a .jar file, I found that [Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) looks at the current directory for an application.yml file.

```
java -jar app-0.3.jar
```

In the current directory, I created an application.yml file with one line:

```
org.xyz.app.title: 'XYZZY'
```

I also used this file to specify the database and other such info.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no externalised config out of the box: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-3-External-config-td4658823.html