# Grails 3.0 logging config in PROD

Tags: tomcat, grails, logback

Grails 3 has the logback plugin. I can configure it and see all the logs when run-app.

But on PRODUCTION I want to use an external logback.groovy file (on tomcat8).

Using Grails 2 I used to externalize the config.groovy with the logging parameters (TRACE, DEBUG, PATH, etc...).

I follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335992/external-properties-file-in-grails-3) and I was able to set up an external config.yml file for my app. But I didn't see how to set this up for logback.groovy.

How to configure logback parameters in an external file for PRODUCTION?

Comment: It is probably not finding your external config file. You can see where logback looks for the config files here: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

As per [docs](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html), in `application-production.yml,` you can define path for an external `logback.groovy` file that will override what is defined in your `grails-app/conf/logback.groovy`.

```
logging:
    config: /Users/me/config/logback.groovy
```